# Problems with libvlc android and TvPlayer from Android TV Framework

Tags: java, android, android-tv, libvlc

I am trying to design a small module to receive rtp traffic and display it in the live channels application of android tv. The application in question receives sound and everything, but when it comes to drawing the image on the screen, this happens to me in the records.

logcat:

```
08-23 02:03:06.339 31050 31195 E VLC     : [e6831cb0/79db] libvlc window: request 1 not implemented
08-23 02:03:06.339 31050 31195 D VLC     : [d573bc30/79db] libvlc vout display: VoutDisplayEvent 'resize' 1920x1080
08-23 02:03:06.339 31050 31195 D VLC     : [e6831db0/79db] libvlc gl: looking for opengl es2 module matching "any": 1 candidates
08-23 02:03:06.341 31050 31195 D VLC     : [e6831db0/79db] libvlc gl: no opengl es2 modules matched
08-23 02:03:06.341 31050 31195 E VLC     : [e6831cb0/79db] libvlc window: request 1 not implemented
08-23 02:03:06.341 31050 31195 D VLC     : [d573bc30/79db] libvlc vout display: VoutDisplayEvent 'resize' 1920x1080
08-23 02:03:06.341 31050 31195 D VLC     : [d573bc30/79db] libvlc vout display: no vout display modules matched
08-23 02:03:06.341 31050 31098 E VLC     : [ed07a330/797a] libvlc video output: video output creation failed
08-23 02:03:06.343 31050 31098 D VLC     : [d5751cb0/797a] libvlc spu text: removing module "freetype"
08-23 02:03:06.345 31050 31098 D VLC     : [d5753830/797a] libvlc scale: removing module "yuvp"
08-23 02:03:06.345 31050 31098 D VLC     : [d5752bb0/797a] libvlc scale: removing module "swscale"
08-23 02:03:06.346 31050 31098 E VLC     : [e684a730/797a] libvlc decoder: failed to create video output
```

AppPlayer.java:

```
/*
 * Copyright 2016 The Android Open Source Project.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package io.neirth.player;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.media.PlaybackParams;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.Surface;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

import com.google.android.media.tv.companionlibrary.TvPlayer;

import org.videolan.libvlc.IVLCVout;
import org.videolan.libvlc.LibVLC;
import org.videolan.libvlc.Media;
import org.videolan.libvlc.MediaPlayer;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * A wrapper around ExoPlayer which implements TvPlayer. This is the class that actually renders
 * the video, subtitles and all these sorts of things.
 */
public class AppPlayer implements TvPlayer {
    private LibVLC libVlc;
    private MediaPlayer player;

    /**
     * AppPlayer constructor
     * @param context Context
     */
    public AppPlayer(Context context) {
        ArrayList<String> options = new ArrayList<>();
        options.add("-vv");
        options.add("--aout=opensles");
        
        libVlc = new LibVLC(context, options);
        player = new MediaPlayer(libVlc);
    }

    /**
     * Load media
     * @param mediaUri Media URI
     */
    public void loadMedia(String mediaUri) {
        loadMedia(Uri.parse(mediaUri));
    }

    /**
     * Load media
     * @param mediaUri Media URI
     */
    public void loadMedia(Uri mediaUri) {
        final Media media = new Media(libVlc, mediaUri);
        media.setHWDecoderEnabled(true, false);
        media.addOption(":clock-jitter=0");
        media.addOption(":clock-synchro=0");
        media.addOption(":network-caching=1000"); // In milliseconds
        media.addOption(":sout-keep");
        media.addOption(":audio-time-stretch");

        player.setMedia(media);

        media.release();
    }

    /**
     * Release player
     */
    public void release() {
        player.release();
        libVlc.release();
    }

    /**
     * Set surface
     * @param surface Video surface
     */
    @Override
    public void setSurface(Surface surface) {
        final IVLCVout vlcVout = player.getVLCVout();
        if (surface != null) {
            DisplayMetrics dm = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics();
            vlcVout.setVideoSurface(surface,null);
            vlcVout.setWindowSize(dm.widthPixels, dm.heightPixels);
            vlcVout.attachViews();
        } else {
            vlcVout.detachViews();
        }
    }


    /**
     * Get current position
     * @return Current position in milliseconds
     */
    @Override
    public long getCurrentPosition() {
        return (long) (player.getPosition() * 1000);
    }


    /**
     * Get duration
     * @return Duration in milliseconds
     */
    @Override
    public long getDuration() {
        return player.getLength();
    }


    /**
     * Start or resume player
     */
    @Override
    public void play() {
        player.play();
    }


    /**
     * Pause player
     */
    @Override
    public void pause() {
        player.pause();
    }


    /**
     * Stop player
     */
    public void stop() {
        player.stop();
    }


    /**
     * Seek to
     * @param position Position in milliseconds
     */
    @Override
    public void seekTo(long position) {
        float pos = (float) position;
        pos /= 1000;
        player.setPosition(pos);
    }


    /**
     * Set volume
     * @param volume Volume between 0 and 1
     */
    @Override
    public void setVolume(float volume) {
        player.setVolume((int) (volume * 100));
    }


    @Override
    public void setPlaybackParams(PlaybackParams params) {}

    @Override
    public void registerCallback(Callback callback) {}

    @Override
    public void unregisterCallback(Callback callback) {}
}
```

I would appreciate an answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is coming from your `setSurface()` method.

Here's a self contained working sample

```
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import org.videolan.libvlc.LibVLC;
import org.videolan.libvlc.Media;
import org.videolan.libvlc.MediaPlayer;
import org.videolan.libvlc.util.VLCVideoLayout;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class JavaActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {
    private static final boolean USE_TEXTURE_VIEW = false;
    private static final boolean ENABLE_SUBTITLES = true;
    private static final String ASSET_FILENAME = "bbb.m4v";

    private VLCVideoLayout mVideoLayout = null;

    private LibVLC mLibVLC = null;
    private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final ArrayList<String> args = new ArrayList<>();
        args.add("-vvv");
        mLibVLC = new LibVLC(this, args);
        mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(mLibVLC);

        mVideoLayout = findViewById(R.id.video_layout);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mMediaPlayer.release();
        mLibVLC.release();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        mMediaPlayer.attachViews(mVideoLayout, null, ENABLE_SUBTITLES, USE_TEXTURE_VIEW);

        try {
            final Media media = new Media(mLibVLC, getAssets().openFd(ASSET_FILENAME));
            mMediaPlayer.setMedia(media);
            media.release();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Invalid asset folder");
        }
        mMediaPlayer.play();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        mMediaPlayer.stop();
        mMediaPlayer.detachViews();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok yes, but the framework itself gives me a Surface object, how could it be integrated into your example?

Comment: Please share your full code. And see https://code.videolan.org/videolan/libvlc-android-samples